# Inconsistency jasmine test with tick and auditTime

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

After check several posts I can't find a solution to the issue I'm faced of.

I have a form which is saved each 2 seconds in database if a value changes.

So in the app.ts looks like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        auditTime(2000),
        distinctUntilChanged(...),
        concatMap(() => {
          return this.saveform();
        })
      )
      .subscribe(...);
```

And to test this, I add some changes in the form

app.test.ts:

```
it('should save each 2 seconds',  fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn<any>(component, 'saveForm').and.returnValue(of({}));

      component.form.get('monthOpening').setValue('April');
      component.form.updateValueAndValidity();
      tick(2000);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      component.form.get('monthClosing').setValue('december');
      component.form.updateValueAndValidity();
      tick(500);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      component.form.get('customers').setValue(80);
      component.form.updateValueAndValidity();
      tick(1000);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      component.form.get('daysOfWeek').setValue(['sat', 'sun']);
      component.form.updateValueAndValidity();
      tick(2000);

      expect(component['saveForm']).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    }));
```

I know the code of app is working, I can see values are properly saved. But I don't know why, when I launch the all tests of the test class, sometimes I got the error :

```
Expected spy saveForm to have been called 2 times. It was called 1 times.
```

It happens totally randomly. Most of the time, test passes, but sometimes not.
I tried with jasmine.clock, setTimeOut, but nothing works perfectly well.

Do you know where can it come from ? And if there is a better solution to fix this ?

Comment: Did you tried adding 1 millisecond extra like 2001? Beyond that, is better to pass the time like parameter to set a shorter time in the test and a default (2000) in the parameter, because if you have many tests, It will run slowly (2 seconds per test).

Comment: This trick didn't work unfortunately. I moved the test in issue into another describe. For now, it seems working, I wonder if there weren't too much tests inside the same describe causes values were not updated sometimes, because they were changed several times in several different tests.